# Reconflict the merge, after incorrect manual merge conflict resolution

Tags: git, merge, conflict

After resolving a merge conflict and committing, it has become apparent that **my manual merge conflict resolution was wrong**. I have already staged, committed, and pushed the repo. **How can I get the conflicting file back into the conflicting state, such that I might resolve it differently?**

Note that it is too late for `git checkout -m` as I've already committed the incorrect merge resolution.

Comment: have a look at http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html for a step by step guide to various fixups. The big question is whether you can force push (overwrite) your bad merge, or is it too late for that now?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a clean working directory, I would hard reset back to before the merge, start a new branch, and perform the merge again.  You could then perform a diff between the original merge result branch and your new branch to get a patch file to apply on the original branch.  Since you have already pushed your result, you will want to create a new commit correcting the merge commit rather then performing a force push after editing the history.

Overly detailed version:

If your current history looks something like this and `c` is the merge commit you want to change.

```
a - c - d <-HEAD/master
   /  
  b
```

Starting from a ***completely*** clean working directory.

```
git branch old_merge <sha1 of c>  // create branch for original merge
git checkout -b new_merge <sha1 of a> // create and checkout branch before merge
// re-merge branch
```

This will create something like this...

```
 old_merge
    ∨
a - c - d <-master
  X  
b - c' <-HEAD
    ∧
 new_merge
```

That's probably really confusing but hopefully you get the idea.  Now you can perform a diff between the `old_merge` branch and the `new_merge` branch to get the changes you will need to make on master.

```
git diff old_merge..new_merge
```

You could use the `patch` UNIX utility to apply the difference between the two branches after you have checked out master again.

```
git checkout master
git diff old_merge..new_merge | patch -p1
```

Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if you are confused by anything.

Comment: How would one `hard reset back to before the merge`? The commits from both branches are all intertwined.

Comment: Do you know the SHA1 code for the merge commit?  Would that be easy for you to find?  If so, reset back to the merge commit, then perform a `git reset --hard HEAD^` this will reset to before the merge.  Or you could just keep repeating that command until you get to right before the merge.

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` might be helpful here as well to see a graphical representation of your repository.

Comment: Thank you bnorm. I don't think that hard reseting to HEAD^ will help, but I will try in the morning when I get back to work. I'll comment and possibly accept then. In the meantime, a healthy +1. Thanks.