# Resume a merge conflict resolution at a later time

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, meld, mergetool

## Situation

I'm merging files and I stopped because it was time to call it a day, but I hadn't finished the merge.

## Problem

I wanted to make sure that I could resume the merge, and I couldn't find any information about this online so I tried it myself. The result being that I now have a partially merged filed, and the .orig, but not the modified local or remote.

## Question

How do I resume this partial merge conflict resolution without having to start all over again?

## What I did, exactly.

I merged a commit in to the current branch. Then I ran `git mergetool` which is `meld`. I said "ugh. . .its getting late, I can finish tomorrow." and saved all three files. Then I thought "maybe I should check to make sure I CAN resume tomorrow" so I try `git mergetool` again, but it says tells me that no files need merging.

I then do nothing and leave it in an uncommitted state thinking that at this point I can only do more harm.

## What I've found.

The closest thing I've found that might be helpful is [Reconflict the merge, after incorrect manual merge conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887615/reconflict-the-merge-after-incorrect-manual-merge-conflict-resolution) which isn't especially helpful.

What this would suggest is that I save what I have else where (ie `mv file file.bu`) do a hard reset, move the backup file back into place, then try the merge again so that I at least don't need to start completely over again.

However, since I haven't committed yet, unlike that poster, I figure there might be more i can do.

Comment: Git's support for suspending and resuming merges is not very good. I prefer to avoid `git mergetool` which insists on doing all the files without stopping. If you remember which files are done and which aren't, there may be a way to recover relatively simply, but you still have to completely merge any one file all the way through when letting `git mergetool` manage the operations.

Comment: There was only one messy file. In general, I try to avoid merging (or even commiting) more than one file at a time unless the changes are trivial.

Comment: In that case, save the partial merge (move the updated file out of the way) and use `git checkout -m <file>` to restore the merge-conflict and unmerged state. You can then run `git mergetool` again, or just edit the partially-merged file and use your merge-so-far side file to get back into the merge process.

Comment: For whatever reason, that did not work, and I ended up just starting from the beginning. Next time I'm just going to be more careful.

Comment: That's odd. It suggests that Git somehow lost the undo (`REUC`) record from the index. I don't think `git mergetool` does anything that would cause that, but I could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you saved the files the easiest option maybe to restart the merge.